# Foreign letters ÅÄÖ hve been replaced by other characters in my VBA-code. Both strings and range names have been affected. Why?

Tags: vba, excel

Foreign letters ÅÄÖ hve been replaced by other characters in my VBA-code. Both strings and range names have been affected. This has happened after I have sent the file to a client.

Obviously I could change the names of variables to not contain ÅÄÖ, although that would be somewhat tedious. But references to worksheets and other things that affect the user interface have also been messed up. Why has this happened? Can I stop it from happening?

Examples before:

```
MsgBox ("Ett oförutsätt fel har skett.")

Range("ActionsColumnAffärsläget")
```

Examples after:

```
MsgBox ("Ett ofšrutsŠtt fel har skett.")

Range("ActionsColumnAffŠrslŠget")
```

Comment: I don't understand how to fix it from your comment. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: I've seen similar problems when the client OS doesn't have the same font loaded.  Can you verify the specific font is loaded?

Comment: It sounds like you are actually seeing the code get changed in the editor itself?  I believe if UTF-8 is being used then you can avoid some of this.  If it's encoded in Windows-1252 or whatever, the Encode sub [here may help you out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133707/how-to-open-excel-file-written-with-incorrect-character-encoding-in-vba)

Comment: @JimmySmith: Yes, the makro stops working and I can see the different characters in the VBA Editor. Will changing encoding of the file to UTF-8 solve the problem?

Comment: I'd drop that function into another workbook and see if it does.  I don't know if they were thinking of a plain text/CSV or not with the Encode function there.  The OP on that question didn't follow up with Best Answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of typing the characters directly you can replace them by referencing their character code in your message box string like so...

```
MsgBox("Ett of" + Chr(246) + "ruts" + Chr(228) + "tt")
```

It's stupidly verbose way of doing it but should work.

To avoid typing out Chr(###) everytime you need them you can put the characters you need in a short form variable like...

```
Dim a As String = Chr(228)
Dim o As String = Chr(246)

MsgBox("Ett of" + o + "ruts" + a + "tt")
```

Comment: Thank you! It's good to know that it would work, but I really hope there is a simpler solution.

Comment: Updated answer with an alternate method(same process but easier to reference characters over and over again).

Answer (score 0):

Although I find Zack's solution much more elegant than mine (finally, you should type the code only once), here is a work around that will avoid you to write the code as a composition of characters:

- Place your sentence in the range (for example) "A1" of the worksheet "Dictionary" that you will create;
- Write in Range("A1") the value `Ett oförutsätt fel har skett.`
- Change your code with `MsgBox(Sheets("Dictionary").Range("A1")`

Unfortunately there's no way to embedd special characters into the source code, you will need either one or the other work around (usually these are contained in XML files).